# Which datastructure is appropriate for this real world situation?

Tags: data-structures, heap, breadth-first-search

**REAL WORLD PROBLEM:**

Suppose in a bank, customers get their service in front of counters.
And In the counter, they serve as per the serving time of the customers.
A customer with lowest serving time is served before a customer with more serving time than the previous customer. That means,the counter follows shortest job done the first method.

**MY JOB:**

Now my job is to select an appropriate data structure to find the optimized
solution for the counter.
And justify the selection of the data structure broadly (2 pages/200 words or close to it).

**TRIED:**

So from my observation, I thought BFS is the perfect data structure for this situation. But I don't know how to describe it with points and explanation. And i have to broadly explain it.

**EXPECTATION:**

5-6 points on why I choose the data structure with example.

Comment: You should use Heaps(or priority queues)

Comment: why would I use heap and how?

Comment: This question is too broad

Comment: BFS is an algorithm, not a data structure. Minheap (priority-queue) is suited because it is a simulation of real-world queue based on their priorities with fast (O(logn)) insertions and deletions.

Comment: @mrpandey Sounds like 'do-my-homework'...

Comment: I don't know where you got "2 pages/200 words". A page of text is usually about 500 words.

Comment: Look up priority queue (which is often implemented as a binary heap). Hint: the serving time will be the priority. If you understand what a priority queue does, then you should be able to complete this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

First think of **why you should not use BFS?**

Because you want to serve the customer with the shortest job time, so you need to find the job with minimum time.
If you use BFS, you will be traversing all the nodes everytime you want to find the next customer to be served. So, this is not the ideal solution.

**What you need?**

You need some algorithm/data structure which can efficiently find the shortest job whenever a new customer arrives or some customer has been served without traversing the entire list of customers/jobs.
This can be done using **Heaps (Priority queues)**, more specifically `Min-Heaps`.

**Why Heap?**

1. Insertion time in heap is O(logN)
2. Minimum/Maximum element can be extracted with O(logN) time complexity without traversing every node in the heap.
3. Minimum/Maximum element is always at the top node in the min-heap/max-heap respectively no matter what operation (insertion/extraction) you perform.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So now that i decided to use max-heap.This is my plan.First i will put all the serving time of each customer in max heap.then i will short the serving time by deleting the root until no element left in my heap.then i will get the Descending order of serving time.and serve those customer according to the sorted serving time.SO AM I CORRECT?

Comment: You are partially correct. Since you want to serve shortest job first, you'll have to use min-heap and not max-heap. Everything else is correct.